# How to setup auth token security for WebAPI requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In following [this](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) tutorial (modifying it to use an application-based auth string rather than their user model), have the following `TokenValidationAttribute` defined and set this attribute on WebAPI controllers in order to verify that the API request came within my web application:

```
public class TokenValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string token;

        try
        {
            token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization-Token").First();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Missing Authorization-Token")
            };
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2(); // type of encryption
            var authPart = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationTokenPart"];
            var authSalt = GlobalVariables.AuthorizationSalt;
            var authToken = GlobalVariables.AuthorizationToken;

            if (authToken == crypto.Compute(authPart, authSalt))
            {
                // valid auth token
            }
            else
            {
                // invalid auth token
            }

            //AuthorizedUserRepository.GetUsers().First(x => x.Name == RSAClass.Decrypt(token));
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User")
            };
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In my login class, I have the following method defined that returns a `User` object if valid:

```
    private User IsValid(string username, string password)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2(); // type of encryption
        using (var db = new DAL.DbContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users
                .Include("MembershipType")
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user != null && user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt))
            {
                return user;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, the user login validation method doesn't make a WebAPI call that would be to `~/api/User` (that part works).

1)  How do I generate a request with with auth token (only site-generated API requests are valid)?  These could be direct API calls from code-behind, or JavaScript-based (AngularJS) requests to hydrate some objects.

2)  I'm not entirely clear on what `base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);` .  What do I do if the token is valid/invalid?

Answer (score 0):

i think the best practices to send authorization header is by added it on request header

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization-Token",bla bla bla);
```

you can create webrequest or httprequest
maybe you should start from http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-c-sharp.html
or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

in my opinion in order to create proper login security and request you should apply a standard such as openid or oauth

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this, LoginSession contains my token and is static (in my case its a shared service (not static))

```
        public HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2, 0),
            BaseAddress = new Uri(GetServiceAddress())
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        if (LoginSession.Token != null)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", LoginSession.Token.AccessToken));
        }
        return client;
    }
```

notice this line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", LoginSession.Token.AccessToken));
```